# how to build FLANN on ubuntu 64bit for matlab

Tags: matlab, compilation

I'm having a lot of problems building FLANN from source on my linux machine. I managed to build the matlab binding and ended up with a few .m files. However, one such file under the matlab folder was a .cpp file version of the .m file that I needed. Because of this, I was not able to run the FLANN demo code. Does this mean that something went awry during compilation?

I did not get any error message from 'make'. However I did get a few lib missing errors, including CUDA lib and intel TBB from 'cmake'. Not sure if those matter.

this is all i did:

```
$ cd flann-x.y.z-src
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make
```

Comment: This is useful: http://www.cs.uky.edu/~jacobs/tips/flann_matlab.html#multilab

Answer (score 1):

CUDA and TBB are optional, it shouldn't matter that they're not there.

`.m` files are actually plain Matlab source, not anything compiled. In addition to a few `.m` files, you should end up with a `nearest_neighbors.mexa64` (or some other `mex` extension depending on your platform) in the directory `build/matlab/`.

This isn't going to be the same directory with the `.m` and `.cpp` files -- that's the source directory. You should probably run `make install` to gather things either in `/usr/local`, or somewhere else if you do `cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/wherever`. Then you'll have the `.m` and `.mexa64` (but *not* the `.cpp`) files in `/usr/local/share/flann/matlab/`.

Comment: just tried that, some how I only got a bunch of headers and nothing else. I did configure cmake-gui to only build the matlab bindings

Comment: @mugetsu What's happens if you run `make mex_nearest_neighbors` from your build directory?

Comment: I dont seem to have that file at all

Comment: That's not a file; when you've `cd`ed into `build`, just run that command. It's like `make` that you did above but tells it to only build the mex interface and its dependencies; it should either build it or give you what the problem is.

Comment: 'no rule to make target 'mex_nearest_neighbors' is what i got

Comment: That means that cmake isn't trying to build the matlab bindings. Try looking at `MEX_CMD` and `MEXEXT_CMD` in the gui; are they the paths to your matlab's bin/mex, bin/mexext commands? Set them if not.

Comment: yes they are. Still nothing... I feel like the user manual missed out on a lot of details

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14720/discussion-between-dougal-and-mugetsu)